# Prevent submit by disabling button until one value is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I (I guess a solution is to ) disable my submit button until at least one value is selected or typed?

```
   <form name="forma" method="POST" action="used-results.php" id="apliforma">

lots of textboxes and dropdown menus


 <a onclick="forma.submit();" class="btn btn-primary">Search</a>
</form>
```

Comment: by default disable the button write a on change events on dropdown and textbox to check for values of dropdown and textbox and then enable your submit button

Answer (score 2):

You have add a listener to `change` event and check for values

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    validate();

    // In case of validating specific fields
    $('#name, #email').change(validate);
});

function validate(e){
    if ( $('#name').val().length > 0  &&  $('#email').val().length > 0 ) {
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

Comment: A quote is missing here `$('#name, #email`

Comment: Thank you for this. How the code is changed if I let only drop down menus? I basically need it now only for dropdowns. Thank you

Comment: I think, this code works for dropdown menus(select) menu. You can try it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done like this.

```
function ready(){   

    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { 
        inputs[i].addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        document.getElementById('submit').disabled = e.target.value === "" }, false);   
    } 
} 

document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", ready, false )
```

You'll have to add the following tags to your `submit` button `id='submit' disabled='disabled'`.

Cheers.

Comment: I prefer pure JS, however this does not seem to work. My submit button stays disabled

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one which has the dropdown too

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/RQ9M9/1/)

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
    validate();
    $('input,select').change(validate);
});

function validate(e){

    var validation = true;
    $('input , select').each(function(){ 

        if($(this).val()=="")
        {
            validation = false;
        }
    });   

    if ( validation ) {
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);

    } else {

        $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I have only dropdowns?

Comment: Oh thankyou for the example. This is working but I do not want the submit button to be active when all inputs are filled. I need the submit button to be active when at least one is selected